# Passing QObject pointer from a QML object to C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a publisher/subscriber key-value DB class in Qt/C++. The subscribers can connect by passing the key ( string ) , their QObject pointer and the property.
Whenever a value of the subscribed key changes, the properties of the subscribed QObject changes to the new value. Works in Qt/C++ fine.

Now I want to make a view in QML. Is it possible to pass from QML to C++ an object with 3 parameters:

- QObject pointer of the QML object
- property as string
- DB-key as string

?

The preferable solution were, as if the property connects to another property:

```
Item{ myQmlProp: MyCppInst("myDBKey") }
```

**EDIT**
What currently works is this solution:

```
Item{ 
   id:myqmlitem
   myQmlProp: MyCppInst("myDBKey","myQmlProp",myqmlitem) 
}
```

or like this:

```
Item{ 
   id:myqmlitem
   Component.onCompleted:{
      MyCppPublisher.subscribe("myDBKey1","myQmlProp1",myqmlitem)
      MyCppPublisher.subscribe("myDBKey2","myQmlProp2",myqmlitem)  
   }
}
```

Compared to the preferable solution, I have to pass the connected property name and the QML item instance explicitly. But it is ok, many thanks for the answers!
I've hoped to use QML's *this*-Keyword but have learned, that it is currently undefined in QML :-(

Comment: Pass from QML to C++ OR fetch from C++ a QML property value?

Comment: @MohammadKanan Qml should be able to pass the reference to object and property and pass a tag of C++ KeyValue store.  C++ should be able to set that property of that object

Comment: By object I think you you mean _QQuickItem_, I never seen object pointer in QML so  far

Comment: @MohammadKanan QQuickItem is a child of QObject. Every QML item ends up as a QObject pointer in Qt.

Comment: Thats true, but not explicitly qobject

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz - a child is not the same as a derived class.

Comment: @MohammadKanan `QtObject` is a plain `QObject` in QML

Comment: @ GrecKo, I agree , but I meant in QLM you cant derive it as in c++

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz You are saying that it works fine in c++. How are you doing it currently in c++?

Comment: @GrecKo Simple key-value map. Where value has also a list of subscribers and their properties assotiated with the key: https://github.com/vheinitz/cl2/tree/master/kvs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give the object an `id` and pass that id to the function, it will become a `QObject *` on the C++ side. Then you can use the meta system to access properties by name:

```
// qml
Item {
  id: someitem
  ...
  CppObj.cppFoo(someitem)
}

// c++
void cppFoo(QObject * obj) {
  ...obj->property("myDBKey")...
}
```

A reference would do as well, for example `children[index]`.

Comment: Looks good, just tested and it works even like this `myprop:CppObj.cppFoo(someitem)` However, I still have to provide the property name of QML-item, so Cpp knows which property to change like this `myprop:CppObj.cppFoo("myprop",someitem)`
Concerning the id, which you suggest to pass explicitly, is it possible provide this in QML? If I try, i obtain 0x0 in C++. As I've replaced QObject* by void* - I get a pointer, but don't know of which type.

Comment: If all you need to do is access properties, the concrete type doesn't matter, all `QObject` derived get meta data, so you can use `propety()` and `setProperty()` to access the properties regardless of the type. The `id` works in QML and in QML only. It is a "special" property and should be considered more of a "compile time construct".

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz, you can also add "objectname" to your qml item, which is visible in c++. `objectname: "someitem"`

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is a function taking just your dbkey as a parameter, and return a `QObject*` exposing a `Q_PROPERTY` with a `READ` function and `NOTIFY` signal.

This way, you just have to tell with the notify signal the value has changed, and the QML will call the read function automatically.

It could be implemented like that `Item{ myQmlProp: MyCppInst("myDBKey").value }`.

If you know the db keys at compile time you could just add a property for each of them in your `MyCppInst` directly, or if you know them at the creation of your cpp class you could put them in a `QQmlPropertyMap`.
Usage would be like that : `Item { myQmlProp: MyCppInst.myDbKey }` (or `MyCppInst["myDbKey"]` if you need to be dynamic in the QML side).